# New SSD only mounts after issuing blkid command. [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: mount, ssd

I have a new Intel SSD Pro 2500 installed on a SATA3 port as a secondary drive. It is formatted as a primary ext4 partition.

My fstab line is :

```
UUID=1e33881a-d6cf-4933-be70-0aa837641af6 /mnt/ssd  ext4 defaults,discard,noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

The SSD fails to mount during boot:

> "Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /mnt/ssd. Press I to ignore, S to skip mounting, or N for manual recovery"

I skip and login.

The device does show up in fdisk:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 480.1 GB, 480103981056 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 183755 cylinders, total 937703088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa507f0a0

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   937703087   468850520   83  Linux
```

If I then manually mount the SSD, it fails to mount.

If I then issue the `blkid /dev/sdb`command, the device is seen with the correct UUID:

```
/dev/sdb: UUID="1e33881a-d6cf-4933-be70-0aa837641af6" TYPE="ext4"
```

After that point, I can `mount -a`and the SSD mounts correctly. My files are intact and I can go on like nothing happened. Fsck also reports no problems.

Any ideas on why the device is not seen until I use `blkid`?

Comment: Do you get an error during the boot process? If so, please [edit] and add it to your question. Same for the manual `mount` command before running `lsblk`. Have you tried mounting with `/dev/sdb` instead of the UUID? Have you tried `/dev/sdb` instead of the UUID in `fstab`?

Comment: Thanks, It does mount with /dev/sdb manually or in the fstab. I didn't think that was ideal. There is an underlying cause here. And i also believe it is affecting my attempted kernel upgrade. When i use a newer kernel , it will not see my root partition at all and fails to start, throws me into intramfs with no ability to  type.